# C++ Boost Code example of throwing an exception between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, exception, boost

Can someone please show a simple, but complete example of how one could use Boost exception library to transfer exceptions between thread by modifying the code below?

What I'm implementing is a simple multi-threaded Delegate pattern.

```
class DelegeeThread
{
public:
  void operator()()
  {
     while(true)
     {
       // Do some work

       if( error )
       {
         // This exception must be caught by DelegatorThread
         throw std::exception("An error happened!");
       }
     }
  }
};

class DelegatorThread
{
public:
  DelegatorThread() : delegeeThread(DelegeeThread()){}  // launches DelegeeThread
  void operator()()
  {
    while( true )
    {
       // Do some work and wait

       // ? What do I put in here to catch the exception thrown by DelegeeThread ?
    }
  }
private:
  tbb::tbb_thread    delegeeThread;
};
```

Comment: wow...10 hours after the post, and nobody gave an answer? did i word my question badly, or is this problem difficult?

Comment: I would keep in mind that whatever you end up implementing might not be what you expect.  when DelegeeThread wants to trigger an exception in the other thread, the Delegator will likely be doing some unrelated work or could have already terminated, so the catch might be delayed or not happen at all.

Comment: sure, the point you mentioned, i agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assumed you want the delegate to be executed asynchronously on a separate thread. Here is the example using boost threads and exceptions:

```
#include <boost/exception/all.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class DelegeeThread
{
public:
    void operator()( boost::exception_ptr& excPtr )
    {
        try
        {
            int counter = 0;
            while( true )
            {
                // Do some work

                if( ++counter == 1000000000 )
                {
                    throw boost::enable_current_exception( std::exception( "An error happened!" ) );
                }

            }
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
            // type of exception is preserved
            excPtr = boost::current_exception();
        }
    }
};

class DelegatorThread
{
public:
    DelegatorThread() : 
      delegeeThread( boost::bind( &DelegeeThread::operator(), boost::ref( delegee ), boost::ref( exceptionPtr ) ) )
      {
          // launches DelegeeThread
      }

    void wait()
    {
        // wait for a worker thread to finish
        delegeeThread.join();

        // Check if a worker threw
        if( exceptionPtr )
        {
            // if so, rethrow on the wait() caller thread
            boost::rethrow_exception( exceptionPtr );
        }
    }

private:
    DelegeeThread           delegee;
    boost::thread           delegeeThread;
    boost::exception_ptr    exceptionPtr;
};


int main () 
{
    try
    {
        // asynchronous work starts here
        DelegatorThread dt;

        // do some other work on a main thread...

        dt.wait();

    }
    catch( std::exception& e )
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use Boost::Exception to solve this problem. Here is an example of how to use their exception lib to get the exception in the calling thread: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/exception/doc/tutorial_exception_ptr.html

If I remember well, C++0x will provide a mechanism to allow something similar to solve this particular problem.

Comment: yes, i agree we need to use Boost::Exception. I have already looked at an example, but I didnt really get how to use it.